# Erlang: is there an API to 'epmd'?

Tags: erlang

Is there a way to query the name table that epmd daemon manages?

The *nodes()* function isn't very helpful on that front.

NOTE: I am looking for an API **aside** from parsing the output generated through stdout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To query nodes visible for epmd, call:

```
EpmdModule = net_kernel:epmd_module().  % erl_epmd by default
EpmdModule:names().
```

To get a list of connected nodes and their ports:

```
erlang:system_info(dist).
erlang:system_info(dist_ctrl).
```

The first call returns you the table in a [crash dump](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html#distribution_info) format. If you are interested in acquiring the actual ports, use the second one.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with nodes with short-names?  That's mostly what I use and I don't get the expected results.

Comment: Make sure the nodes are connected, e.g. call net_adm:ping(mynode@localhost). Works for me.

Comment: I should have been more explicit: I do not want to have to explicitly "connect" the nodes.  I just want to know which nodes are reachable within the confines of a "short-name domain".

Comment: Sorry, your example with nodes() confused me on what you meant... I added the calls you need on top of the answer.

Comment: Marvelous!  Thanks again Zed!

Answer (score 4):

You get the same answer as Zed's code by doing:

```
net_adm:names()
```

I don't know if that is a more standard way of doing it or not.