# Listing all nodes in an Erlang cluster

Tags: erlang

Is there a way to return all the node names of the nodes in an [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) cluster as a list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`nodes()` should work.

Comment: sidenote: This will not show hidden nodes. use nodes(connected). for that reason.

Answer (score 7):

`net_adm:names()` will return you the nodes that are connected to epmd on the current node.

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478360/erlang-is-there-an-api-to-epmd).

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the hidden nodes connected to a node via nodes(hidden).